# React router v4 - Rendering two components on same route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I have these routes

```
 <Route exact path={`/admin/caters/:id`} component={Cater} />
 <Route exact path={'/admin/caters/create'} component={CreateCater} />
```

When I navigate to the first route I get a cater with a given ID. And the Cater component is rendered

When I navigate to the second route, the CreateCater component is rendered on the page, but I noticed that some redux actions that are used in the Cater component are being run. So both component are somehow being rendered - but I can't figure out why.

Here are the components:

Cater:

```
class Cater extends Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Cater component did mount')
        const { match: { params: { id }}} = this.props
        this.props.get(id)
    }

    render() {
        const { cater } = this.props
        if(!cater) {
            return null
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>
                   ... component data ...
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    const { match: { params: { id }}} = props
    return {
        cater: caterSelectors.get(state, id)
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
    return {
        get: (id) => dispatch(caterActions.get(id))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cater)
```

CreateCater:

```
export default class CreateCaterPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Breadcrumbs />
                <CaterForm />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

When I go to /admin/caters/create' I can see the console.log in the componenDidMount() lifecycle method inside the Cater component.

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: Try swapping the `<Route />` tags (Put /create first), and let me know if that changes anything

Comment: Thank you for the reply @FrankerZ. 
I tried it and it didn't make any difference. 
I tried making url's different in length, so that create was looking like `/admin/cater/create/cater`. And then I didn't have any issues, but that is not how I want to structure my URL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/create` matches `/:id`, so it makes sense that this route matches. I recommend forcing `:id` to look for numeric only:

```
<Route exact path={`/admin/caters/:id(\\d+)`} component={Cater} />
<Route exact path={'/admin/caters/create'} component={CreateCater} />
```

Likewise, you can follow @jabsatz's recommendation, use a switch, and have it match the first route that matches. In this case, you would need to ensure that the `/admin/caters/create` route is the first `<Route />` element matched.

Comment: @David react-router under the hood uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#custom-match-parameters). They explain it a bit in the docs.

Comment: @FrankerZ thank you! This fixed it for me. Didn't know about the (\\d+) either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `:id` is matching with `create` (so, it thinks "see cater with id `create`"). The way to solve this is to put the wildcard matching route last, and wrapping all the `<Routes/>` with a `<Switch/>`, so it only renders the first hit.

Check out the docs if you have any more questions: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch